# Recorrer e insertar 1 o mas resultados de una query en una tabla con un procedimiento almacenado

Tags: sql-server, sql

que tal, quería pedir ayuda con un procedimiento almacenado de sql server 2009, tengo una query la cual recibe un parametro de una columna y esta puede devolver 1 o más resultados, es decir:

select a,b,c from tabla1 where a = '123' ---> esto puede tener 1 o varios resultados y quiero insertarlos en otra tabla.

el parámetro de entrada seria un string.

estoy aprendiendo hacer procedimientos almacenados con sql server pero aun no entiendo bien como hacerlo, ya que solo se hacer procedimientos almacenados simples.

de ante manos muchas gracias

Comment: Hola si haz intentado algo de esto, puedes agregarlo a tu pregunta, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: Hola Jordan, me temo que la versión de SQL Server 2009 no existe :( aunque lo que pretendes realizar pudiera funcionar independientemente de la versión. ¿Has intentado/investigado algo al respecto?

Answer (score 1):

Para tu ejemplo yo te propondría:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TuProcedimiento 
    (@Filtro NVARCHAR(50))
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT a,b,c
    FROM tabla1 
    WHERE a = @Filtro
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas es realizar para lo que estas pidiendo es un INSERT INTO SELECT, eso sí, debes tener en cuenta que las columnas del SELECT deben ser las mismas que las columnas a insertar en la tabla de destino.

Junto a la creación de un procedimiento almacenado que reciba un string se quedaria algo así:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.nombreprocedimiento 
            @nombreparametro NVARCHAR(MAX)
    AS 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tabla2
        SELECT a, b, c
        FROM tabla1
        WHERE a = @nombreparametro
    END
```